# Check native browser support for lazy-loading images

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a script that lazy-loads images, but since chrome 76 there is a 'native' lazy load.

I'm trying to detect whether browser supports native lazy-load or not. But I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by using feature detection on an `img` element:

```
var supportsLazyLoad = ('loading' in document.createElement('img'));
```

Comment: Another similar way of doing it from Google (source: https://web.dev/native-lazy-loading/#how-do-i-handle-browsers-that-don't-yet-support-native-lazy-loading) :
if ('loading' in HTMLImageElement.prototype) {
  // supported in browser
} else {
  // fetch polyfill/third-party library
}